# Setting the path in a for loop in .profile

Tags: arrays, bash, syntax

I am trying to set the PATH in `.profile` through looping over a list of directories, as follows:

```
DIRS=("$HOME/bin"
      "$HOME/.local/bin"
      "$HOME/.ghcup/bin")

for dir in $DIRS; do
    if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
      PATH="$PATH:$dir"
    fi
done
```

But this doesn´t seem to work. The following does work:

```
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by does/doesn't work?

Comment: Put `set -x` and `set +x` around this block of code, so you'll see what it's doing.

Comment: That's not how you loop over an array. It should be `for dir in "${DIRS[@]}"`. Without an index, the array variable expands to the first element.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) finds a serious problem in the code (incorrect use of an array variable).  The report that it produces includes a link to more information about the problem and how to fix it.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: `.profile` should remain POSIX-compliant, which precludes the use of arrays. There's also little reason to worry about whether or not a directory exists before adding it to your path; if it does not exist, path lookup will silently ignore it.